# How to call built in plugin alongside custom plugin with python nosetests

Tags: python, plugins, nosetests

I am trying to write a custom plugin for nosetests ( a plugin to run as a custom selector) which works fine and i can use it by calling

```
nose.run(plugins=[CustomSelectorPlugin()])
```

However i also want to run nose with the built-in xunit plugin but I am unsure as to how to do this.

I have tried

```
nose.main(plugins=[CustomSelectorPlugin()], argv=['--with-xunit'])
```

and calling my program with  --with-xunit option but these do not seem to work (well, everythion runs fine but there is no nosetests.xml generated)

How do i run both my plugin and xunit pragmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem

I needed to call

```
nose.run(addplugins=[CustomSelectorPlugin()])
```

note the `addplugins` (as opposed to `plugins`) call. This allows me to call my program with command line arg `--with-xnuit`. Just having `plugins` meant the default plugin manager was not invoked/called/was overridden.

Also I should mention to be able to specify the args in code the first arg in argv is ignored by nose so something like this should be used:

```
nose.run(addplugins=[CustomSelectorPlugin()], argv=['foo', '--with-xunit'])
```

Hope this helps future googlers